# Tableau Reader unable to read/open a tableau desktop visualization made conecting with sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I made visualisations with Tableau Desktop. My colleagues have Tableau Reader.
Due to jobrequirements, I have to made the visuals connecting with an excel in sharepoint.

Everything went fine, but when my colleagues open it with tableau reader, the following error appears.

The image illustrates the mistkae, is in spanish let me translate it for you:

Impossible to complete action
Incorrect Connexion; Tableau cannot connect with the data source.
Error code: 3EAFBCC8
Tableau does not recognize the data source type
'cloudfire: onedrivesharepoint-excel-direct'. I may be that it is not avalable in this tableau version o that a complement of the connector it is missing in this computer.

A guy a know told me that I should make an extract from each data source (I do not understand what that means)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPOzS.png)

Does anyone knows how to solve this issue?